# Downloaded shapefiles become 1KB when I try to upload to QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, general-function-failure

This problem is happening when downloading multiple GIS files from different sites.

I downloaded 2012.zip from https://www.sos.wa.gov/elections/research/precinct-shapefiles.aspx to see the precinct maps for 2012 in Washington state.

[image]

Everything looks normal, so I extract the data from the zipfile so I can upload it into QGIS with no problems. I go to add a shapefile to my new project, and select the shp file.

[image]

I leave everything in default, and go to add the shapefile.

[image]

Once I've done so, I see that a layer name "Statewide_Prec_2012" has been added but nothing shows up. The area where the map should be is completely blank, despite the layer being selected. I "zoom to layer" and the screen stays the same. I open the attributes table and it's blank. Now, if I go and look at the extracted data from earlier, this is what I find.

[image]

Does anyone have any clue what is happening? I never ran into this issue using ArcGIS but switched to using QGIS so I can work on projects on both of my computers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Creating* a *new* layer means creating a new, empty file from scratch. If you specify the name of an existing file, it will overwrite that. QGIS should have asked you about that.

You need to use the function to *add* an *existing* layer to the project.

Comment: thank you, I was being dumb. I now have added the existing layer to the project. do you know why it overwrote the file to make everything only 1Kb though?

Comment: That's how small an empty Shapefile is. QGIS should have asked or warned you before allowing to overwrite it, did it not?

Comment: I must have missed it. thanks for your help!